# inserting value into database sqlite not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hi i have issue with database SQLITE android

please check my code for reference

when i am going to insert values it returns -1 that i come to know from debug 
which is not inserting values so tell me what is wrong
i am inserting value from list view.

```
public void add_device(String data,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        // database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        for (HashMap<String, String> map : jsonlist) {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(SAVE_COLUMN_NAME, data);
            values.put(SAVE_COLUMN_KEY, map.get(SAVE_COLUMN_KEY));
            values.put(SAVE_COLUMN_VALUE, map.get(SAVE_COLUMN_VALUE));
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Long int1 = db.insert(SAVE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            Log.i("insserted value ", int1 + "");
        }

    }
    /*
     * for(HashMap<String, String> map : mylist){ ContentValues cv = new
     * ContentValues(); cv.put(FILE_NAME, map.get(FILE_NAME)); cv.put(DESC,
     * map.get(DESC)); cv.put(UPLOADED_BY, map.get(DATE_UPLOADED));
     * cv.put(ACTION, map.get(FILE_NAME)); cv.put(ID, map.get(ID));
     * cv.put(FILE_URI, map.get(FILE_URI)); db.insert("tablename", null,
     * cv); }
     */

    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: check logcat..will get hint may be

Comment: it show no such table exist so now how to create table ?

Comment: see my answer..if any query let me know

Comment: `TODO: handle exception`: do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made changes like

```
public void add_device(String data,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist) {
    try {
        database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        for (HashMap<String, String> map : jsonlist) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(SAVE_COLUMN_NAME, data);
            values.put(SAVE_COLUMN_KEY, map.get(SAVE_COLUMN_KEY));
            values.put(SAVE_COLUMN_VALUE, map.get(SAVE_COLUMN_VALUE));
            Long int1 = database.insertOrThrow(SAVE_TABLE_NAME, null,
                    values);
            Log.i("insserted value ", int1 + "");
        }
    }

    /*
     * for(HashMap<String, String> map : mylist){ ContentValues cv = new
     * ContentValues(); cv.put(FILE_NAME, map.get(FILE_NAME)); cv.put(DESC,
     * map.get(DESC)); cv.put(UPLOADED_BY, map.get(DATE_UPLOADED));
     * cv.put(ACTION, map.get(FILE_NAME)); cv.put(ID, map.get(ID));
     * cv.put(FILE_URI, map.get(FILE_URI)); db.insert("tablename", null,
     * cv); }
     */
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that the "-1" value is coming from your Log.i(...) message, so the -1 is the return value of the db.insert(...) call.  The -1 indicates an error occurred.

Instead of using insert, user insertOrThrow(...) and look at the exception for clues as to why there is a problem.

Comment: `public static final String CREATE_SAVE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + " " 
   + SAVE_TABLE_NAME + "(" + SAVE_COLUMN_ID
   + "INTEGER PRIMERY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + SAVE_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"
   + SAVE_COLUMN_KEY + " TEXT," + SAVE_COLUMN_VALUE + " TEXT" + ");";`

can you check it this is true query??

Answer (score 1):

-1 is returned when you are inserting the records.
This can be due to violation of table properties (like conflict between type of data you are inserting and the type of column in table ,is "key" and "Value" column in table are of string type) also there can be several other reasons for this like you may be missing any table column value in insert operation or value of 'SAVE_COLUMN_NAME','SAVE_COLUMN_KEY','SAVE_COLUMN_VALUE' doesn't matches with respective column names in table .

[while running app open separate command prompt and write adb logcat ) and show the result here (specifically when you try to insert the record) so that we have more information related to issue]

[EDIT]

OK so i think i have found the problem

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

and you are inserting statement

```
   Long int1 = db.insert(SAVE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

**INSERT SHOULD BE DONE USING WRITABLE DATABASE NOT READABLE DATABASE.**

Here SQLiteDatabase db is a Readable Database it should be a Writable database

change

```
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

to

```
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```